# XMLReader is skipping elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml, xmlreader

I have the following XML file (with dummy data)

```
<Query>
    <QuerySQL Source="Dbname" Sql="SQL statement" />
  </Query>
  <Query>
    <QuerySQL Source="Dbname" Sql="SQL statement" />
  </Query>
  <Query>
    <QuerySQL Source="Dbname" Sql="SQL statement" />
  </Query>
  <Query>
    <QuerySQL Source="Dbname" Sql="SQL statement" />
  </Query>
  <Query>
    <QuerySQL Source="Dbname" Sql="SQL statement" />
  </Query>
  <Query>
    <QuerySQL Source="Dbname" Sql="Sql statement">
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
      </Parameters>
    </QuerySQL>
  </Query>
  <Query>
    <QuerySQL Source="Dbname" Sql="Sql statement">
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
      </Parameters>
    </QuerySQL>
  </Query>
  <Query>
    <QuerySQL Source="Dbname" Sql="Sql statement">
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
      </Parameters>
    </QuerySQL>
  </Query>
  <Query>
    <QuerySQL Source="Dbname" Sql="Sql statement">
      <Parameters>
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
        <Parameter Type="Type" />
      </Parameters>
    </QuerySQL>
  </Query>
```

The problem is, the first Query elements are read perfectly in my XMLReader.

Then when it hits the ones with parameters, it skips every other query.

I can't figure out why. It just does not show up in the reader at all.

Here is my reader method;

```
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xmlString.ToString());
      using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader, GetXmlReaderSettings())) {
        while (reader.Read() && !reader.EOF) {
          if ((reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (reader.Name == "Query")) {
            if (reader.ReadToDescendant("QuerySQL")) {
              m_sqlQuery = reader.GetAttribute("Sql");
              m_doublePointCounter = m_sqlQuery.Split(':').Length - 1;
              m_source = reader.GetAttribute("Source");
              if (reader.ReadToDescendant("Parameters")) {
                while (reader.ReadToFollowing("Parameter") && m_parameterCount < m_doublePointCounter) {
                  m_parameterCount++;
                  var types = reader.GetAttribute("Type");
                  m_paramList.Add(types);
                }
              }
            }
          }
}
```

I hope anyone can help me to figure this out.

What I need is the method to read every single Query element and read it.

Comment: It is valid Xml according to the XML specification.  It is just not well formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReadToFollowing` method passes through all `Parameter` elements.
To avoid this, you need to read the subtree.

```
if (reader.ReadToDescendant("Parameters"))
{
    using (var innerReader = reader.ReadSubtree())
    {
        while (innerReader.ReadToFollowing("Parameter") && m_parameterCount < m_doublePointCounter)
        {
            m_parameterCount++;
            var types = innerReader.GetAttribute("Type");
            m_paramList.Add(types);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! This works, thank you very much. I was so close :D

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;



namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            var results = doc.Descendants("Query").Select(x => new
            {
                source = (string)x.Element("QuerySQL").Attribute("Source"),
                sql = (string)x.Element("QuerySQL").Attribute("Sql"),
                parameters = x.Descendants("Parameter").Select(y => new { type = (string)y.Attribute("Type") }).ToList()
            }).ToList();


        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Do you have an array at root level?  Do you have any namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not well formed - you have multiple `<Query>` root tags. To make the XML valid you need to nest that repeating `<Query>` tag within a root tag.

Until you fix that problem there is nothing you can do - XML processors are *required* to reject your input file. I am not surprised that LINQ failed to process it. I am quite surprised that you did not get a parsing error from the code that you posted.

Comment: I have that, it is in the 'Queries' root tag. So thats not the problem. 

I just tried, when I close every SQLQuery at the end with a /> then it does detect all the queries... But then it does not parse the parameters.

Comment: Check your question - the XML does not include the `<Queries>` root tag. Please edit the question now, and include the entire XML message (including any namespace definitions on the root tag)